# Logging queries with Spring Boot and spring data cassandra 3.0.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

In older versions of spring-data-cassandra it was possble to create a QueryLogger bean and register it to the cluster to get some query logging. Now with spring-data-cassandra 3.0.1 the QueryLogger class is gone and I fail to find an alternative.

How can I enable logging of queries? If possible including Consistency Level.

Answer (score 0):

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      consistency-level: quorum
      serial-consistency-level: quorum

logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        data:
          cassandra:
            core:
              cql:
                CqlTemplate: DEBUG
```

Comment: It doesn't work (or prove me wrong). toString() on CqlTemplate isn't implemented so you get an object reference, not a readable query.

Comment: Line 163 to 165 in CqlTemplate 
```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
 logger.debug("Executing CQL Statement [{}]", cql);
}
```
This logger line in CqlTemplate is printing the below debug line

2020-11-03 21:23:36.308 DEBUG 22897 --- [           main] o.s.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate  : Executing CQL Statement [CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS name_type (first_name text, last_name text, middle_name text);]

Comment: Using spring-data-cassandra:3.0.4

Comment: Fixed after version 3.0.5